# Customizing the list of listings generated by \lstlistoflistings?

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, tocloft

I'm using `listings` in my document, and its command `\lstlistoflistings` to generate the list of listings. The problem is that I've customized all the other lists (TOC, LOF and LOT). More precisely, I've changed the color of the page number, removed the leading dots and move the page number to appear right after the entry text (i.e. the page number is no longer right-aligned). Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

% Define color theme
\newcommand{\titleColor}{\color[rgb]{0.616, 0.0627, 0.176}}
\newcommand{\partChapterNumColor}{\titleColor}
\newcommand{\tocPageColor}{\color[rgb]{0.0980, 0.329, 0.651}}

% Rules
\newcommand{\thinRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.25pt}}

% Customize heading appearance
\newcommand{\partSize}{\Huge}
\newcommand{\partStyle}{\lsstyle\scshape}
\newcommand{\chapterSize}{\huge}
\newcommand{\chapterStyle}{\lsstyle\scshape}
\newcommand{\chapterAfter}{\thinRule}
\newcommand{\sectionSize}{\Large}
\newcommand{\sectionStyle}{\lsstyle\scshape\MakeTextLowercase}
\newcommand{\subsectionSize}{}
\newcommand{\subsectionStyle}{\itshape}
\newcommand{\numberStyle}{\fontsize{60pt}{72pt}\selectfont\partChapterNumColor}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
            {\filcenter}
            {\numberStyle\thepart}
            {0pt}
            {\partSize\partStyle}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
            {}
            {\filleft\numberStyle\thechapter}
            {0pt}
            {\chapterSize\chapterStyle}
            [\chapterAfter]
\titleformat{\section}
            {\sectionSize}
            {\thesection\quad}
            {0pt}
            {\sectionStyle}
\titleformat{\subsection}
            {\subsectionSize}
            {\thesubsection\quad}
            {0pt}
            {\subsectionStyle}

% Customize "Table of ..." appearance
% Customize headings
\newcommand{\fixCtfHeadingBeforeSpacing}{\vspace*{1ex}} % Needed to make chapter
\newcommand{\fixCtfHeadingAfterSpacing}{\vspace*{0.5ex}} % layout coherent
\newcommand{\renewPrintXTitle}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{#1}[1]{%
    \fixCtfHeadingBeforeSpacing
    \chapterSize\chapterStyle ##1
    \fixCtfHeadingAfterSpacing
    \par\chapterAfter
  }
}
\renewPrintXTitle{\printtoctitle}
\renewPrintXTitle{\printlottitle}
\renewPrintXTitle{\printloftitle}

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\partChapterNumColor\partStyle}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\chapterStyle}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionfont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigurefont}{}
\renewcommand{\cfttablefont}{}
\newcommand{\cftlistingfont}{}
% No leader dots
\renewcommand*{\cftpartdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectiondotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsectiondotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand*{\cftfiguredotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand*{\cfttabledotsep}{\cftnodots}
% Set page numbers immediately after entry text
\newcommand{\tocEntryPageSep}{\hspace{2em}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\tocEntryPageSep}
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\tocEntryPageSep}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionleader}{\tocEntryPageSep}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionleader}{\tocEntryPageSep}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureleader}{\tocEntryPageSep}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cfttableleader}{\tocEntryPageSep}
\renewcommand{\cfttableafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
% Customize page numbers
\newcommand{\tocPageStyle}{\tocPageColor}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\tocPageStyle}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\tocPageStyle}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionpagefont}{\tocPageStyle}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionpagefont}{\tocPageStyle}
\renewcommand{\cftfigurepagefont}{\tocPageStyle}
\renewcommand{\cfttablepagefont}{\tocPageStyle}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\lstlistoflistings

\section{new section}

bla bla bla

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=test code]
Test
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Now I've figured out how to change the fonts by redefining one of `listings`'s internal commands:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@lstlisting}[2]{%
  \@dottedtocline{1}
                 {0em} % Indent
                 {\cftfigurenumwidth} % Listing number width
                 {\cftlistingfont#1} % Entry text font
                 {\tocPageStyle#2}% % Page number font
}
\makeatother
```

But how do I remove the dots and move the placement of the page number? Also, it appears that the entries in the LOL appears slightly higher up in the document compared to the other lists.

Also note that I'm using `memoir`, if that's of any use.

Comment: Create a _complete_ example!

Comment: @Herbert: Sorry. Done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to register the list of listings to **tocloft**; I've found this to work

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup\let\newcounter\@gobble\let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
  \globaldefs\@ne \let\c@loldepth\@ne
  \newlistof{listings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
\endgroup
\let\l@lstlisting\l@listings
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{\listoflistings}
\renewcommand{\cftlistingsfont}{\itshape}
```

The last line is just to show that commands of the type `\cftlistings...` are available for customizing the entries' appearance exactly in the same way as the normal ones.

The "slightly higher up" business depends on the fact that the standard classes issue `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}` and the same for `lot`; so we do the same for `lol`.

You can typeset the list either by `\lstlistoflistings` or `\listoflistings`.

## FOR memoir

When **memoir** is used, one has to act in a slight different way

```
\begingroup\makeatletter
\let\newcounter\@gobble\let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
  \globaldefs\@ne \let\c@loldepth\@ne
  \newlistof{listings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
  \newlistentry{lstlisting}{lol}{0}
\endgroup
```

Now one can customize the appearance of entries in the list of listings with commands of the form `\cftlstlisting...`; these should typeset the list of listings exactly as the others.

```
\renewcommand{\cftlstlistingdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftlstlistingleader}{\tocEntryPageSep}
\renewcommand{\cftlstlistingafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftlstlistingpagefont}{\tocPageStyle}
```

In the case of **memoir** no vertical adjustment at the beginning of the lists seems to be necessary.

## Addition

In order to add a separation in the "list of listings" for listings in different chapters, do

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
  \addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}
\makeatother
```

or, more simply,

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\insertchapterspace
  {\addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I tried copy-pasting the code into my document, but I get an error saying that `lstlistoflistings` is undefined (however that now happened). Could you please be so kind and use my complete example (which I just included) and modify it such that the List of Listings appears as the Table of Contents?

Comment: The vertical adjustment is needed. How do I include that?

Comment: It doesn't in my test based on your example; I only added a `figure` environment and `\listoffigures`.

Comment: Hm, it does in my real document... I tried adding `\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
` from your previous example but that just messed up the whole thing (although it did the vertical alignment).

Comment: Did you add it between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`?

Comment: No, I did not. And now it looks perfectly! ^^ Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that the other listings have a vertical space between listings belonging to the same chapter, whereas the "List of Listings" defined here does not. Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: @gablin: see edited answer

Comment: That did it! Wish I could upvote this answer more.

Answer (score 3):

put this before `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter     
\let\l@lstlisting\l@section     
\makeatother
```

Comment: This actually worked quite well. The only problem is that the entries are indented.

Comment: then copy the definition of `\l@section` and rename it to `\l@lstlisting}` and redefine the values.

Answer (score 3):

The [`titletoc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlesec) package works for any contents generated by `\contentsline` and `\numberline`. For a new type of contents, just use

```
\contentsuse{<content type>}{<content file extension>}
```

Then we can use `\titlecontents` command to customize the list just like ToC/LoF/LoT's.
It's much easier than patching `tocloft` package.

And here is an example for `\lstlistoflistings`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsuse{lstlisting}{lol}
\titlecontents{lstlisting}[2em]
              {\addvspace{0.25pc}}
              {\textbf{Code \thecontentslabel} }
              {}
              {\titlerule*[0.5em]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}
              []

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test]
Some code
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```