# How to add a colon after listing label?

Tags: listings

I want to add a colon ":"  after each lstlistingname in the lstlistoflistings.

At the moment the it shows me "Code 1 StatusCalculator Initialize....."
But I want a colon after lstlistingname "Code 1: StatusCalculator Initialize..."

I didn't get it to run. Can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\definecolor{grey}{gray}{0.9}

\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstloadlanguages{Ruby}
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\color{black},
commentstyle = \ttfamily\color{red},
keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue},
stringstyle=\color{orange},
backgroundcolor=\color{grey},
columns=fullflexible}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

\let\oldlstlistoflistings\lstlistoflistings
\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{%
  \begingroup%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{\lstlistingname~\oldnumberline}%
  \oldlstlistoflistings%
  \endgroup}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}

\begin{document}

 \renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Codelisting}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Codelisting}
 \lstlistoflistings
 \newpage

  \begin{lstlisting}[language=Ruby, caption=StatusCalculator Initialize, label=initialize]
  def initialize(project_id)
    @project = Project.find(project_id)
  end
  \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related question: [Customizing the list of listings generated by \lstlistoflistings?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27645)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve what you want, the trick

```
\let\oldlstlistoflistings\lstlistoflistings
\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{%
  \begingroup%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{\lstlistingname~\oldnumberline}%
  \oldlstlistoflistings%
  \endgroup}
```

is not enough...

You have to load the package `tocloft` and play with it.

First of all, you have to register the list of listings to `tocloft`, as explained in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27648/27635) of egreg with the code

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup\let\newcounter\@gobble\let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
  \globaldefs\@ne \let\c@loldepth\@ne
  \newlistof{listings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
\endgroup
\let\l@lstlisting\l@listings
\makeatother
```

Then, playing a little with `tocloft` commands:

```
\setlength{\cftlistingsindent}{1.5em}
\renewcommand*{\cftlistingspresnum}{\lstlistingname~}
\settowidth{\cftlistingsnumwidth}{\cftlistingspresnum}
\addtolength{\cftlistingsnumwidth}{2.3em}
\renewcommand{\cftlistingsaftersnum}{:}
```

Finally, remove the first mentioned code with the discussed ones, that is modify your MWE to

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\definecolor{grey}{gray}{0.9}

\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstloadlanguages{Ruby}
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\color{black},
commentstyle = \ttfamily\color{red},
keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue},
stringstyle=\color{orange},
backgroundcolor=\color{grey},
columns=fullflexible}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\let\newcounter\@gobble\let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
  \globaldefs\@ne \let\c@loldepth\@ne
  \newlistof{listings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
\endgroup
\let\l@lstlisting\l@listings
\makeatother

\setlength{\cftlistingsindent}{1.5em}
\renewcommand*{\cftlistingspresnum}{\lstlistingname~}
\settowidth{\cftlistingsnumwidth}{\cftlistingspresnum}
\addtolength{\cftlistingsnumwidth}{2.3em}
\renewcommand{\cftlistingsaftersnum}{:}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}

\begin{document}

 \renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Codelisting}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Codelisting}
 \lstlistoflistings
 \newpage

  \begin{lstlisting}[language=Ruby, caption=StatusCalculator Initialize, label=initialize]
  def initialize(project_id)
    @project = Project.find(project_id)
  end
  \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

and you will get

[image]