# Formatting \listoftables and \listofalgorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms

I need a special format for the \listoffigures and the \listofalgorithms.

It should be:

```
List of Tables
      Table 1: T1.....................1
```

and respective

```
List of Algorithms
      Algorithm 1: A1.................1
```

For the Table I found:

```
\renewcommand*\cfttabpresnum{Table~}
\settowidth{\cfttabnumwidth}{\cfttabpresnum}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnumb}{$\;$$\;$:~}
```

which works perfectly.

For the Algorithms I found

```
\let\oldlistofalgorithms\listofalgorithms
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{%
  \begingroup%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{Algorithmus:~\oldnumberline}%
  \oldlistofalgorithms%
\endgroup}
```

from here: [Add the word "Algorithm" before each entry in the List of Algorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96969/add-the-word-algorithm-before-each-entry-in-the-list-of-algorithms)
which also works. But the style is

```
 List of Algorithms
         Algorithm 1 A1................1
```

so the ":" is missing. I tried to solve it by myself but I couldn't figure out. Could you held me please?

Greets,Tony

Comment: What do you use to produce your algorithms?

Comment: See this answer of mine: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126850/27635. That one does the same thing for listings. Try to adapt it for algorithms.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we know which is the best way to go?

Comment: @Werner: I use lstlistings to write my pseudocode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to first register the list of algorithms so that [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) is aware of it; this can be done, for example using [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27648/3954) to [Customizing the list of listings generated by \lstlistoflistings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27645/3954). The relevant part, adjusted to the case of algorithms, is

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \let\newcounter\@gobble
  \let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
  \globaldefs\@ne
  \let\c@loadepth\@ne
  \newlistof{algorithms}{loa}{\listalgorithmname}
\endgroup
\let\l@algorithm\l@algorithms
\makeatother
```

Once this has been done, you can use the `\cft...` family of commands to customize the entries format:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \let\newcounter\@gobble
  \let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
  \globaldefs\@ne
  \let\c@loadepth\@ne
  \newlistof{algorithms}{loa}{\listalgorithmname}
\endgroup
\let\l@algorithm\l@algorithms
\makeatother

\renewcommand\cfttabaftersnum{:}
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{Table~}
\cftsetindents{tab}{1.5em}{5em}

\renewcommand\cftalgorithmsaftersnum{:}
\renewcommand\cftalgorithmspresnum{Algorithm~}
\cftsetindents{algorithms}{1.5em}{7em}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\listofalgorithms
\cleardoublepage

\begin{table}
\centering A
\caption{test table}
\end{table}

\begin{algorithm}
\centering A
\caption{test algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{table}
\centering A
\caption{another test table}
\end{table}

\begin{algorithm}
\centering A
\caption{another test algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

An image of the list of tables:

[image]

An image of the list of algorithms:

[image]

Comment: Probably the indentation can be adjusted to be the same in both lists...

Comment: @karlkoeller the indentation of entries in both lists is the same (the second image is a little shifted to the right): entries in both lists begin at a distance of `1.5em` from the left margin.

Comment: I mean the spacing after the number. That is I would use something like `\setlength{\cftalgorithmsindent}{1.5em} \settowidth{\cftalgorithmsnumwidth}{\cftalgorithmspresnum} \addtolength{\cftalgorithmsnumwidth}{2.3em}` instead of `\cftsetindents{algorithms}{1.5em}{7em}`. The same for the LOT.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for the same above for "lstlistings" this should do it:

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup\let\newcounter\@gobble\let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
  \globaldefs\@ne \let\c@loldepth\@ne
  \newlistof{listings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
\endgroup
\let\l@lstlisting\l@listings
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{\listoflistings}

\renewcommand\cftlistingsaftersnum{:}
\renewcommand\cftlistingspresnum{Listing~}
\cftsetindents{listings}{1.5em}{7em}
```