# Custom name of listing in list of listings with minted not working

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, minted, german, lstlisting

I am using the minted package to highlight source code and also to add a list of listings. My code already looks like it should:

```
\begin{listing}[hb]
    \inputminted[frame=single,linenos]{c}{code/hello_world.c}
    \caption{Hello World in C}
    \label{hello_world_c}
\end{listing}
```

[image: Code snippet, working as intended]

I used the following commands to change the autoref name and the caption name:

```
\providecommand*{\listingautorefname}{Qc.}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Qc.}}
```

I also removed the chapter counter in the list of listings with the following commands:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter} 
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{listing}{chapter}
```

Now I insert the list of listings like this:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Quellcodeverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\listoflistingscaption}{Quellcodeverzeichnis}
\listoflistings
\clearpage
```

And my list of listings looks like this:

[image: The actual list of listings]

But instead I would like it to look like this:

[image: List of listings as it should look like]

I already tried inserting the name with
`\renewcommand{\cftlistingpresnum}{Qc.~}`

But I get the following error: `LaTeX Error: \cftlistingpresnum undefined.`

I also tried using `\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}` but then the commands that worked before are undefined:

`LaTeX Error: \listingscaptionundefined.`
`LaTeX Error: \listoflistingscaptionundefined.`

I use ShareLaTeX for compiling my files.
I read that the babel package might cause some problems, here is a list of packages I also use:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[chapter]{minted}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx}
\usepackage[german,algosection,boxed]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{thmbox}
```

**Edit:** Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[chapter]{minted}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usemintedstyle{vs}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Settings of Quellcodeverzeichnis
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{listing}{chapter}

% Doesn't work: LaTeX Error: \cftlistingpresnum undefined.
% \renewcommand{\cftlistingpresnum}{Qc.~}

\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Qc.}}
\providecommand*{\listingautorefname}{Qc.}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Table of contents
% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Quellcodeverzeichnis
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Quellcodeverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\listoflistingscaption}{Quellcodeverzeichnis}
\listoflistings
\clearpage

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Content
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{LaTeX-Template}
\label{ch:anhang}

My Hello World C program is right here: \autoref{hello_world_c}

\begin{listing}[hb]
\begin{minted}[frame=single,linenos]{c}
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\caption{Hello World in C}
\label{hello_world_c}
\end{listing}
\clearpage


\end{document}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you provide a **full** minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). ... so just compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Hello and thanks for answering, I added a minimal working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with the help of this answer: [Customizing the list of listings from minted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260801/customizing-the-list-of-listings-from-minted/261048#261048)

Here is my result:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newlistof{listing}{lol}{Quellcodeverzeichnis}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Settings of Quellcodeverzeichnis
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{listing}{chapter}

\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{%
    name={Qc.},
    fileext=lol}

\renewcommand{\cftlistingpresnum}{Qc.~}
\setlength{\cftlistingnumwidth}{2cm}

\begin{document}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Table of contents
% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Quellcodeverzeichnis
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Quellcodeverzeichnis}
\listoflistings
\clearpage

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Content
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{LaTeX-Template}
\label{ch:anhang}

My Hello World C program is right here: \autoref{hello_world_c}

\begin{listing}[hb]
\begin{minted}[frame=single,linenos]{c}
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\caption{Hello World in C}
\label{hello_world_c}
\end{listing}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```