# Adding a colon to entries in a list of algorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithm2e

I'm trying to create a list of algorithms such that the a colon appears after every algorithm number. I've included a MWE below that produces the following,

[image]

I'd like to modify this by adding a colon after the algorithm number,

```
Algorithm 1.1: Pseudocode caption . . . . 2
```

I have seen similar questions asked ([Formatting \listoftables and \listofalgorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131575/formatting-listoftables-and-listofalgorithms)), however this solution does not work for me. I believe it is because their example uses `algorithm` while I am using `algorithm2e`. I haven't been able to solve this issue.

The "LIST OF ALGORITHMS" header needs to remain as it is shown in the MWE, I cannot have the default header that usually appears with `\listofalgorithms`

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,algochapter]{algorithm2e}  
\usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\loacontents}{\@starttoc{loa}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}{Algorithm~\oldnumberline}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{LIST OF ALGORITHMS}
\end{center}
~\\ % Empty lines
~\\
\loacontents
\endgroup

\pagebreak

\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Pseudocode caption.}
    asdf        
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minor adjustment to the redefinition of `\numberline`. Instead, collect the regular argument, and add a `:` suffix when you pass that on to `\oldnumberline`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,algochapter]{algorithm2e}  

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\loacontents}{\@starttoc{loa}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{Algorithm~\oldnumberline{#1:}}
\begin{center}
  \bfseries LIST OF ALGORITHMS
\end{center}
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\loacontents
\endgroup

\pagebreak

\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Pseudocode caption.}
  asdf
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```