# Setting Entries of List of Listings in LaTeX. Package Listings

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, listings

I'm trying to put an hyphen after the entries of the "List of Listings" as follows:

## List of Codes

Code 1 **--** First Code ................................ 7

Code 2 **--** Second Code ............................... 8

With the following code ...

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,oneside,dvipsnames,a4paper,%
chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE,english]{abntex2}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}         %  Listings
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Codes}%

\lstset{
            language = [LaTeX]{TeX}
}

\AtBeginDocument{ %
            \counterwithout{lstlisting}{chapter}
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[caption={First Code}]{code1.tex}
\lstinputlisting[caption={Second Code}]{code2.tex}

\end{document}
```

I have:

## List of Codes

Code 1 First Code ................................ 7

Code 2 Second Code ............................... 8

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package and part of [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27648/3954) to [Customizing the list of listings generated by \lstlistoflistings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27645/3954):

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,oneside,dvipsnames,a4paper,%
chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE,english]{abntex2}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}         %  Listings
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Codes}%

\lstset{
  language = [LaTeX]{TeX}
}

\AtBeginDocument{ %
  \counterwithout{lstlisting}{chapter}
}

\newlength\mylen

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\newcounter\@gobble\let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
  \globaldefs\@ne \let\c@loldepth\@ne
  \newlistof{listings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
  \newlistentry{lstlisting}{lol}{0}
\makeatother
\endgroup

\renewcommand\cftlstlistingpresnum{\lstlistingname~}
\settowidth\mylen{\cftlstlistingpresnum\cftlstlistingaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftlstlistingnumwidth{\mylen} %
\renewcommand\cftlstlistingaftersnum{\hfill\textendash\hfill}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={First Code}]
code1
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Second Code}]
code2
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. I've got better result with {\hfill\textendash\hfill} instead of {\,--} in \renewcommand\cftlstlistingaftersnum{\,--}.

Comment: @Ulysses You're welcome. Yes, that gives better results. I edited my answer to include it.