# Why the empty space size is increasing each call to my calculate listing header command?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, listings, calculations, abnt

I learned how to create a list of codes on my thesis on the question [Setting Entries of List of Listings in LaTeX. Package Listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228936/setting-entries-of-list-of-listings-in-latex-package-listings) and I put that command on another file with english tiles as `\lstlistingname{Code}` and `\lstlistlistingname{List of Codes}`.

However my thesis is written in multiple languages, therefore later I need to recreate the code table titles `\lstlistingname{Códigos}` and `\lstlistlistingname{Lista de Códigos}` when I switch the language of the thesis as explained on the question [Is it possible to keep my translation together with original text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5076/is-it-possible-to-keep-my-translation-together-with-original-text)

```
% Calculate the size of the header
\newcommand{\calculatelisteningsheader}
{
    \renewcommand\cftlstlistingpresnum{\lstlistingname~}
    \settowidth\mylen{\cftlstlistingpresnum\cftlstlistingaftersnum}
    \addtolength\cftlstlistingnumwidth{\mylen} %
    \renewcommand\cftlstlistingaftersnum{\hfill\textendash\hfill}
}
```

On this following example, I created the command `\calculatelisteningsheader` to reevaluate the headings size of the titles:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,oneside,a4paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Setting Entries of List of Listings in LaTeX. Package Listings
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228936/setting-entries-of-list-of-listings
\newlength\mylen

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Codes}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
    \let\newcounter\@gobble\let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
    \globaldefs\@ne \let\c@loldepth\@ne
    \newlistof{listings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
    \newlistof{lstlistoflistings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
    \newlistentry{lstlisting}{lol}{0}
\makeatother
\endgroup

% Calculate the size of the header
\newcommand{\calculatelisteningsheader}
{
    \renewcommand\cftlstlistingpresnum{\lstlistingname~}
    \settowidth\mylen{\cftlstlistingpresnum\cftlstlistingaftersnum}
    \addtolength\cftlstlistingnumwidth{\mylen} %
    \renewcommand\cftlstlistingaftersnum{\hfill\textendash\hfill}
}

% Ensure it is called at least one time
\calculatelisteningsheader

% Later...
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Codes}
\calculatelisteningsheader


\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={First Code}]
code1
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Second Code}]
code2
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However something is going wrong. The size of the empty space is more than doubled on the second time I call `\calculatelisteningsheader`:

[image]

Why the space size is increasing each call to `\calculatelisteningsheader`?

---

## Update

As suggested by [@koleygrso](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/120578), I already tried removing the indentation and adding a `%` on the `\calculatelisteningsheader` but it stills the same:

```
\newcommand{\calculatelisteningsheader}
{%
\renewcommand\cftlstlistingpresnum{\lstlistingname~}
\settowidth\mylen{\cftlstlistingpresnum\cftlstlistingaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftlstlistingnumwidth{\mylen} %
\renewcommand\cftlstlistingaftersnum{\hfill\textendash\hfill}
}
```

Comment: Related to: [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that everytime `\calculatelisteningsheader` is called, `\cftlstlistingnumwidth` length is being added on (because of `\addtolength`).

A quick workaround would be to store the old `\cftlstlistingnumwidth` as a length beforehand, outside of the `\calculatelisteningsheader` macro, and using this when "adding to length" of `\cftlstlistingnumwidth`.
This way, even if `\calculatelisteningsheader` is called multiple times, the sum remains consistent.

See the following code -- I've marked out the relevant changes.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,oneside,a4paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Setting Entries of List of Listings in LaTeX. Package Listings
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228936/setting-entries-of-list-of-listings
\newlength\mylen

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Codes}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
    \let\newcounter\@gobble\let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
    \globaldefs\@ne \let\c@loldepth\@ne
    \newlistof{listings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
    \newlistof{lstlistoflistings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
    \newlistentry{lstlisting}{lol}{0}
\makeatother
\endgroup

\newlength\cftlstlistingoldnumwidth% <---------
\setlength\cftlstlistingoldnumwidth{\cftlstlistingnumwidth}% <---------
% Calculate the size of the header
\newcommand{\calculatelisteningsheader}
{%
    \renewcommand\cftlstlistingpresnum{\lstlistingname~}%
    \settowidth\mylen{\cftlstlistingpresnum\cftlstlistingaftersnum}%
    \setlength\cftlstlistingnumwidth{\dimexpr\cftlstlistingoldnumwidth+\mylen}% <---------
    \renewcommand\cftlstlistingaftersnum{\hfill\textendash\hfill}%
}

% Ensure it is called at least one time
\calculatelisteningsheader

% Later...
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Codes}
\calculatelisteningsheader
\calculatelisteningsheader % <------- For testing purposes
\calculatelisteningsheader % <------- For testing purposes
\calculatelisteningsheader % <------- For testing purposes

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={First Code}]
code1
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Second Code}]
code2
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: lstlisting code]