# How to NOT start List of Listings in a new page

Tags: listings, tocloft

Here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[%
english,
cdfont=false,
cdtitle=color,
cdfont=nodin
]{tudscrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{roman}

  \tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Listings}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}  %%%%%%% RESETTING PAGE NUMBERING TO 1.
\chapter{Requirement/Limitation}
\section{Layout Dependancy}
\section{corner Dependancy}
\chapter{Performance on a Large Design}
\section{Design}
\section{Results}
\chapter{Future Works}


\begin{appendices}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}
\chapter{Parasitic Extraction}
\chapter{Development of Box Methodology}
\blindtext
\end{appendices}
\newpage

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\end{document}
```

It outputs **List of Figures** and **List of Tables** in the same page but **List of Listings** in a new page. If I comment the `\usepackage{tocloft}` then, I get the **List of Listings** in the same page. But I need this package for some other purpose. Is there a clean work-around to bring the heading in the same page?

Comment: Where can we find this `tudscrrprt` class?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it is shipped with TexLive version 2016.

Comment: It also can be compiled in ShareLaTeX and Overleaf, FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tudscrreprt` bases on the KOMA-Script class `scrreprt`. So it loads package `tocbasic` to format the lists like LOF, LOT etc. and therefore it is not recommended to use package `tocloft` with this class. You will get warnings.

Additionally your `\addcontentsline` commands for the lists could result in a wrong page number for the TOC entry.

If the lists should not start a new page, then the lists should not use chapter level. So I would suggest something like:

```
\documentclass[%
  english,
  cdfont=false,
  cdtitle=color,
  cdfont=nodin,
  listof=totoc,% TOC entry for lists
  listof=leveldown% use section for the list headings
]{tudscrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{scrhack}% <- added
\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \tableofcontents
  \addchap{Lists}
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables
  \lstlistoflistings
  \cleardoubleoddpage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \chapter{Requirement/Limitation}
  \section{Layout Dependancy}
  \section{corner Dependancy}
  \chapter{Performance on a Large Design}
  \section{Design}
  \section{Results}
  \chapter{Future Works}
\end{document}
```

Maybe you can ask how to replace `tocloft` by the possibilies of `tocbasic` for the other purpose.

---

If you really want to load `tocloft` with `tudscrreprt` (not recommended!!), then you can use [this answer of @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27648/43317):

```
\documentclass[%
  english,
  cdfont=false,
  cdtitle=color,
  cdfont=nodin
]{tudscrreprt}
\usepackage{}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}% adds LOF and LOT to TOC

\makeatletter
\begingroup\let\newcounter\@gobble\let\setcounter\@gobbletwo
  \globaldefs\@ne \let\c@loldepth\@ne
  \newlistof{listings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
\endgroup
\let\l@lstlisting\l@listings
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{\listoflistings}
\renewcommand\cftafterloltitle{\addchaptertocentry{}{\lstlistlistingname}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Requirement/Limitation}
\section{Layout Dependancy}
\section{corner Dependancy}
\chapter{Performance on a Large Design}
\section{Design}
\section{Results}
\chapter{Future Works}
\end{document}
```